# Pushing items to the end of a stack in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following ordering in python:

```
items = SELECT * FROM items WHERE is_hidden = 0 ORDER BY id ASC
# [1,2,5,9]
items_at_end_of_stack = SELECT * FROM items WHERE is_hidden = 1 ORDER BY id DESC
# [4,3]
items_ordered = list(items) + list(items_at_end_of_stack)
# [1,2,5,9,4,3]
```

Would there be a way to do this with a single query in mysql? Basically I want to push certain items to the end of the stack and not have to convert everything to two lists to do the list-adding in python.

Comment: In this case, just get rid of the `is_hidden` in the `WHERE` clause, and `ORDER BY is_hidden, id`  instead.  Course, this assumes `is_hidden` is not stupidly named, so it's actually used as a boolean.  :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY is_hidden, id DESC
```

should work...